# Replacing the Backbone in YoloV3

Tags: object-detection, yolo

I want to replace the backbone of YoloV3 from darknet-53 to MobileNetV3 for object detection. How do I implement it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.